# I'm trying to use media queries to make my site responsive, and I'm failing. I wonder if I'm missing something simple?

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, media-queries

The website that I'm working on has a background image and a separate header image, and I'd like to use media queries to get them as well the text on the header image to resize appropriately for different screens. I've played around with a lot of options based on different tutorials, but I still don't think my stylesheet is working as it should be. Here's an example of my css:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
 img {max-width: 90%;}
   #wrapper { max-width: 90%; }
   #wrapperbg { max-width: 90%; }
   #header { max-width: 90%; }
   #navlist { max-width: 90%; font-size: 80%; font-family: agency, 

sans-serif; }
   #navlist2 { max-width: 90%; }
   #navlist li {max-width: 10%; font-size: 1.5em; font-family: sans-serif; }
}
```

I've included the line in the header as well:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"/>
```

I'm fairly new to trying to use media queries for a responsive design, so I know I'm making some ignorant mistake. Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px) and (orientation : portrait)
{
    //...
}
```

For more see [**this**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Answer (score 0):

I had problems using media queries with a wordpress theme, and I fixed it by downloading a special plugin for mobile phones and creating style sheets that way.  It is just called "mobile css".  I actually created media queries within the plugin for things like landscape vs. portrait on the iPad, etc.